# Trying to Pull Single PHP Variable from JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables, extract

Here is the result on the page when using `print_r($result);`

```
Array
(
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => Elvis
            )

    )

)
```

I would like to pull this out of the array and use it as a PHP variable.  I have tried `extract`, `while loops` and a variety of other solutions, but I am not finding the right syntax to make this happen.  What is the easiest way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$var = $result['result'][0]['username'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sooo close.

Comment: You beat me by 35 seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the array is consistent, just like you showed it, then you just need

```
$username=$result['result'][0]['username'];
```

Comment: I appreciate it.  @AbraCadaver was just before you on this, but you solution worked as well.